# Numpy histogram parameters

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I want to get histogram of an image but I have an error that I don't know how to solve it. It's due to I don't know what are right values for numpy histogram parameters:

My code is:

```
rojo = np.histogram(imagen[:,:,0], 
range(0,256), bins = 256)
verde = np.histogram(imagen[:,:,1], 
range(0,256), bins = 256)
azul = np.histogram(imagen[:,:,2], 
range(0,256), bins = 256)
```

The error is:

> 9     rojo = np.histogram(imagen[:,:,0], range(0,256), bins = 256)
>
> 10     verde = np.histogram(imagen[:,:,1], range(0,256), bins = 256)
>
> 11     azul = np.histogram(imagen[:,:,2], range(0,256), bins = 256)
>
> TypeError: string indices must be integers

What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is `imagen` really an array?

Comment: Also, you're passing the `bins` parameter twice. Once as positional argument on position 2, and once as a keyword argument on position 3.

Comment: Imagen is a path where the image is.

Comment: You need to actually read the image first

Comment: I read the image and now the error is histogram() has multiple values for bins. So I delete range and works. But can I change values for range?

Comment: As Nil Werner explained, you mixed positional and keyword arguments in the call to `histogram`.  The signature of the function begins `histogram(a, bins=10, range=None, ...)`.When you gave `range(0, 256)` as the second positional argument, it was assigned to the `bins` parameter.  So the next argument in your call, `bins = 256`, attempts to reassign the `bins` parameter, which results in the error.  There are a few ways to fix that; I suggest using keywords for both arguments: `np.histogram(imagen[:,:,2], bins=256, range=range(0, 256))`

Comment: If I type range = range(0,256) the error too many variables to unpack is displayed